# UpSampling1D in keras insanely slow?

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to build an autoencoder in Keras, everything is going fine but when I add the UpSampling1D layer and run the code and try to get a model summary the program just freezes forever. My problem is that I have an input and output size of 220500, the convolutional layers have no problems with this and compile almost instantly. However the upsampling layers start to become insanely slow when the number of layers to upsample reach about 50 000 and basically freeze. Is there any way around this or is it some inherent limitation in the upsample layer? Also, why would this be? How come a convolution can handle much larger sizes than upsampling? :S

Here's my actual code:

```
def autoencoder(input_dim):

input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim,1))
encode = Conv1D(filters=1,kernel_size=10,strides=2,activation="relu",padding='same')(input_layer)
encode = BatchNormalization()(encode)
n=20
for i in range(15):
    encode = Conv1D(filters=1,kernel_size=10,strides=2,activation="relu",padding='same')(encode)
    encode = BatchNormalization()(encode)

decode = Conv1D(filters=1,kernel_size=10,strides=1,activation="relu",padding='same')(encode)
decode = UpSampling1D(2)(decode)
decode = BatchNormalization()(decode)
for i in range(14):
    decode = Conv1D(filters=1,kernel_size=10,strides=1,activation="relu",padding='same')(decode)
    decode = UpSampling1D(2)(decode)
    decode = BatchNormalization()(decode)

decode = Conv1D(filters=1,kernel_size=10,strides=1,activation="sigmoid",padding='same')(decode)
autoencoder_model = Model(input_layer, decode)
autoencoder_model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder_model.summary()
return autoencoder_model
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @jeevaa_v nope, but I did come up with a workaround sort of. Use several dense layers with a small amount of units, connect them to each other in a tree structure so that you can upscale your output. Imagine a basic tree where each node is a dense layer with maybe 10 units, then it branches off into two separate dense layers, also with 10 units. In order to not separate it into a ”left and right” part you also connect the left sides most right child to the right side. This gives you approximatle O(n^2) in performance where n is the number of units in one tree node. Works decently for me.

Comment: I did a simple workaround using UpSampling2D. It seems to be faster. So, you set the other dimension size to be 1.

Comment: @jeevaa_v That's odd, but good to know :)